# cakephp : getting pagination link in json format

Tags: json, rest, cakephp, pagination, instagram

I am developing a REST API using CakePHP and want to implement the Instagram API pagination style which looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/puppy/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&max_id=13872296",
        "next_max_id": "13872296"
    }
}
```

I have not used any authorization or whatever, so the `access_token` part can be ignored. My main motive is to get the pagination links (jump links preferably) as JSON data, so I can use it in my JSON serialized view. Because the usual code:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
```

doesn't work and simply displays the equivalent HTML code.
Is there any way I can get it like the Instagram API?

Comment: You should create the url yourself based on the `$this->Paginator->params()` values

Comment: can you please give an example code. for example, lets say i have limited the number of results per page as 7. for that i define'maxLimit' => 7 in Paginator settings. Now what would be the format to generate the link to display next 7 resuls using the method you mentioned. Please elaborate, i am in a big confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something as follow

```
$url = 'http://yourapp.com/pages/index';
$returnArray = array(
    .....
    'pagination' => array(
        'next_url' => null,
        'prev_url' => null
    )
);

if($this->Paginator->hasNext()) {
    $returnArray['pagination']['next_url'] = $url.'/page:'. ($this->Paginator->current()+1);
}

if($this->Paginator->hasPrev()) {
    $returnArray['pagination']['prev_url'] = $url.'/page:'. ($this->Paginator->current()-1);
}

echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

If you want, you can add more named params to the url:

`$params['pagination']['next_url'] = $url.'/page:'.$this->Paginator->current()+1.'/order:name/direction:asc';`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code was exactly what i needed. I had to edit it a little as the function Paginator->current returns a string, you can directly write Paginator->current())+1.I simply added an intval() before it to get the desired result. although the link comes with escape character but it is more than what i was hoping to  get. I seriously dont have words to thanks you. Thanks a lot, you have been a lifesaver. :)
ps: i'm putting the edited code in the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to noslone, i have got the answer. here is the final edited code:

```
$url = 'http://yourapp.com/pages/index/limit:7';
$returnArray = array(
.....
'pagination' => array(
    'next_url' => null,
    'prev_url' => null
)
);

if($this->Paginator->hasNext()) {
$temp = intval($this->Paginator->current())+1;
$returnArray['pagination']['next_url'] = $url."/page:".$temp;
}

if($this->Paginator->hasPrev()) {
 $temp = intval($this->Paginator->current())-1;
$returnArray['pagination']['next_url'] = $url."/page:".$temp;
}
```

echo json_encode($returnArray);

just two changes : first don't forget to add limit:value" to your url and secondly use intval with the Paginator->current.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Paginator helper generates the front-end link, and when you click on it, it will generate next link. 
I do not think you can use it directly to form the Instagram alike API.

Comment: is there any way by which maybe we can overload the usual paginate method to get the link for next url in the controller? Because the only option with me is to get the link in controller and store it as variable. Then only it can be accessed as a link in the view.

Comment: I do not think so. Because Paginator helper is used for views(front end html). 
I think your API functions should accept needed parameter and figure out what data to show dynamically.